# hindi fonts problem

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, unicode, localization, .ttf

I want to practise hindi typing, 
I have installed hindi fonts how ever when selecting fonts and trying to type in Hindi I get only English words following are snapshots
You can see I have selected hindi font
[image]

and image below will show that when I type I only get English words 
[image]

I have also tried creating a .fonts.conf file in my $HOME directory as per instructions here http://www.binarytides.com/display-hindi-unicode-fonts-on-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-linux/

but it did not helped.
What can I do, I need to practise typing as we do with English Keyboards so I do not want to go for phonetic kind of typing styles, plain typewriter kind of typing.I am on Ubuntu 12.04